# how to handle if server response is empty using jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery

i am trying in different ways to handle the null data when server response is empty. i googled but i didn't find any solution, all are php related. I need help to fix this issue.

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "my url",
        data: {
            p1: 'predator',
            p2: 'JSON'
        },
        //global:false,
        //async:false,
        dataType: "xml",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#mydisplay').html('<h2>Loading initial data...</h2>');
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#mydisplay").hide();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#display1").hide();
            $(data).find("root").each(function () {
                a = $(this).find("img").text();
                b = $(this).find("desc").text();
                c = $(this).find("direc").text();
                d = $(this).find("rating").text();
                if (a != "" && b != "" && c != "" && d != "") {
                    $("#disimg").append("image:" + a + "<br>Desc:" + b + "<br>Director:" + c + "<br>Rating:" + d + );
                }
            });
        }, //success
        error: function (request, error) {
            $("#display1").hide();
            //alert('Network error please try again!');
            $("#mydisplay").html('<center><h1> OOPS! </strong> Network error, Data not found..</center></h1>');
        }

    });

});
```

I tried in success function `if(data=""){alert("data not found");}` but it didn't work. How can i display the custom message in complete function. if try to put "data not found" message in complete function, if no data, it displayed correctly otherwise it displayed the success data along with custom message "data not found". Please help me on this.

Comment: Please take the time to format your question/code properly. It makes it easier for us to read and understand it, and in turn easier to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `if(data="")` is an assignment not a comparison, use `===`

Comment: Sorry for my typo mistake. i tried if(data=="") and for my code i properly aligned why should it looks unaligned i don't understand. Anyway i will aligned my code again

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to try to `console.log` the results first.

If you do;

```
if(data==""){
alert("data not found");
}
```

This will work **only** if the `response` is *empty* or equal to `""`. What about in case there were *errors* on the way from your server side codes?...

Those *errors* will be part of the `data` and `data` will no longer be `==` to `""`.

I'll suggest you first do a simple `console.log(data)` to make sure of the desired results.

Comment: I will check once again in console